# Telebot. How to accept input inside callback_query_handler?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telebot

I am writing a telegram bot using the **TeleBot** module.

In the body of the function, clicks on the `InlineKeyboardMarkup` buttons are processed.

Inside it there should be a conditional block: "if the button with `callback_data = ok` is pressed, then...", where in the `else` block it is necessary to wait for input from the user.

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda callback: callback.data)
def check_callback(callback):
    if (callback.data == 'ok'):
        if not weekdays_list:
            bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, "Press at least one button.")
        else:
            bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, "Please enter what time you want to be notified, in the format 'hhmm'.")
```

**I tried this:** (created at the end of the program, before `bot.infinity_polling()` function ***answer***)

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda callback: callback.data)
def check_callback(callback):
    if (callback.data == 'ok'):
        if not weekdays_list:
            bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, "Press at least one button.")
        else:
            msg = bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, "Please enter what time you want to be notified, in the format 'hhmm'.")
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, answer)

def answer():
    print('Wow, it works!')

bot.infinity_polling()
```

**So:**

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def answer(message):
    print('Wow, it works!')
    
@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda callback: callback.data)
def check_callback(callback):
    if (callback.data == 'ok'):
        if not weekdays_list:
            bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, "Press at least one button.")     
        else:
            msg = bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, "Please enter what time you want to be notified, in the format 'hhmm'.")
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, answer)
```

**And like this:**

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda callback: callback.data)
def check_callback(callback):
    if (callback.data == 'ok'):
        if not weekdays_list:
            bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, "Press at least one button.")
    else:
        msg = bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, "Please enter what time you want to be notified, in the format 'hhmm'.")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, answer)

        @bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
        def answer(message):
            print('Wow, it works!')
```

Please suggest how can this be done?

Comment: Use `bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, answer)` with `answer` function without decorator.